# Python: pick appropriate datatype size (int) automatically

Tags: python, numpy

I'm allocating a (possibly large) matrix of zeros with Python and numpy. I plan to put unsigned integers from 1 to `N` in it.

`N` is quite variable: could easily range from 1 all the way up to a million, perhaps even more.

I know `N` prior to matrix initialisation. How can I choose the data type of my matrix such that I know it can hold (unsigned) integers of size `N`?

Furthermore, I want to pick the *smallest* such data type that will do.

For example, if `N` was 1000, I'd pick `np.dtype('uint16')`. If `N` is 240, `uint16` would work, but `uint8` would also work and is the smallest data type I can use to hold the numbers.

This is how I initialise the array. I'm looking for the `SOMETHING_DEPENDING_ON_N`:

```
import numpy as np
# N is known by some other calculation.
lbls = np.zeros( (10,20), dtype=np.dtype( SOMETHING_DEPENDING_ON_N ) )
```

cheers!

### Aha!

Just realised numpy v1.6.0+ has `np.min_scalar_type`, [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.min_scalar_type.html#numpy.min_scalar_type). D'oh! (although the answers are still useful because I don't have 1.6.0).

Comment: I've just realised I can do `np.array([N]).dtype` to get an appropriate `int` dtype (`int32`,`int64`) but would like `uint`.

Comment: Now I've worked out I can do `np.array([N]).astype('uint')` to get the appropriate `uint8` dtype, **except** that it starts at `uint32`. For example, `np.array([54]).astype('uint')` returns a dtype of `uint32`, but I want `uint8`, being the minimal type that can still hold unsigned integers up to 54.

Comment: When you use a basic dtype like ``'uint'`` or ``float`` Numpy uses the default for the system you are on, which is why you get ``uint32``.  To get the non-default size you need to specify the size explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about writing a simple function to do the job?

```
import numpy as np

def type_chooser(N):
    for dtype in [np.uint8, np.uint16, np.uint32, np.uint64]:
        if N <= dtype(-1):
            return dtype
    raise Exception('{} is really big!'.format(N))
```

Example usage:

```
>>> type_chooser(255)
<type 'numpy.uint8'>
>>> type_chooser(256)
<type 'numpy.uint16'>
>>> type_chooser(18446744073709551615)
<type 'numpy.uint64'>
>>> type_chooser(18446744073709551616)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "spam.py", line 6, in type_chooser
    raise Exception('{} is really big!'.format(N))
Exception: 18446744073709551616 is really big!
```

Comment: If you want to be really clever, you could implement this using `np.log2(N)` !

Comment: Aha, this was what I was after. I did come up with my own version using bitshifts, but it's basically the same as yours. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create a mapping of maximum value to type, and then look for the smallest value larger than N.

```
typemap = {
  256: uint8,
  65536: uint16,
   ...
}

return typemap.get(min((x for x in typemap.iterkeys() if x > N)))
```

Comment: cheers! I ran with @wim's because it didn't rely on me making a dict, although I realise your approaches are essentially the same.

Comment: The dict isn't really being used as a dict here, though. You could just as easily use a tuple of 2-tuples.

Comment: You could do a rounded log base 2 to use as a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

For interest, here is the version I had been toying with until @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams and @wim posted their answers, using bitshifts:

```
def minimal_uint_type(N):
    bases = [8,16,32,64]
    a = [N>>i for i in bases]
    try: dtype = bases[len(np.nonzero(a)[0])]
    except: raise StandardError('{} is really big!'.format(N))
    return dtype
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code for myself and I think it is more general.

```py
def np_choose_optimal_dtype(arr, return_dtype=False):
    """
    Return the optimal dtype for a numpy array.
    """
    assert np.array_equal(np.floor(arr), arr), 'np array must be integer'
    min_val = np.min(arr)
    max_val = np.max(arr)
    type_list = [np.uint8, np.uint16, np.uint32, np.uint64]
    if min_val < 0:
        type_list = [np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64]
    for d_type in type_list:
        if np.iinfo(d_type).min <= min_val and np.iinfo(d_type).max >= max_val:
            if return_dtype:
                return d_type
            return np.array(arr, dtype=d_type)
            
    raise ValueError('Could not find a dtype for the array.')
```